# How to pause/loop/continue inside a loop waiting for onclick action?

Tags: javascript

Form onsubimt calls a function where then a pop up msg appears asking if user wants to continue with their action before submiting the form. This means that the function from the form Onsubimt needs to wait for the user last input in order to fully execute the form.

This is the code below:

```
<form name="mailF" id="mailF" method="post" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return get_answer(null)" action="Mail-sender.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   //more form data...
</form>

<div id="question">
    Are you sure you want to send this email?
    <button onclick="get_answer('Send')">Yes</button>
    <button onclick="get_answer('No')">No</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 function get_answer(val){
      document.getElementById("question").style.display = "block";
      if(val === "Send"){
          return true;
      }else if(val === "No"){
          return false;
      }else{
          get_answer(val);
      }
 }
```

This is how I tried to solve this problem. I keep looping the function get_answer until the value is either "Send" or "No" however on console i am getting the following error. **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**, how else could I implemented this without having this error, is there a better way to implement this?

NOTE: I left **event.preventDefault();** on form because otherwise it would execute the action after the trowing error.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just leave out the

```
else{
      get_answer(val);
  }
```

part. It's totally unnecessary.
Instead of just returning true or false, submit the form in case of "Send".

```
if(val === "Send"){
    document.getElementById("mailF").submit();
}
```

Comment: But then the function would execute only once and would return true and that means it would trigger the action from form

Comment: ohh i see what you mean :) yeah thats easier

Comment: In the "No" case, you have to do something appropriately, like hiding the form or going to another page.